# Components, Isolate function, and 'referential transparency'

Tags: cyclejs

I have a (rather philosophical) question which refers to `cyclejs` components : [Is isolate() referentially transparent?](http://cycle.js.org/components.html).

Looking at the simplified code, reproduced thereafter, I could not discriminate any source of 'impurity'. Is that because the not simplified code introduces it, or because the function would return two different objects with two different references?

In that case, would not those two objects have the same behaviour (i.e. listening and reacting to the same events on the same targets, and producing different vTree$ but which encapsulate exactly the same sequence?). And if that is so, aren't those two objects essentially the same, i.e. replacing one by the other anywhere in the program should not change anything? Which means `isolate` is referentially transparent? Where did I go wrong?

Actually if both calls returns different objects which cannot be substituted, how do those objects differ?

```
function isolate(Component, scope) {
  return function IsolatedComponent(sources) {
    const {isolateSource, isolateSink} = sources.DOM;
    const isolatedDOMSource = isolateSource(sources.DOM, scope);
    const sinks = Component({DOM: isolatedDOMSource});
    const isolatedDOMSink = isolateSink(sinks.DOM, scope);
    return {
      DOM: isolatedDOMSink
    };
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I could not discriminate any source of 'impurity'. Is that because the not simplified code introduces it, or because the function would return two different objects with two different references?

The simplified code does not introduce impurity. The impurity comes from the fact that the parameter `scope` defaults to `newScope()` if it is not specified. [The actual implementation of `isolate()`](https://github.com/cyclejs/isolate/blob/master/src/index.js) has:

```
function isolate(dataflowComponent, scope = newScope()) {
  // ...
}
```

Where `newScope()` is:

```
let counter = 0

function newScope() {
  return `cycle${++counter}`
}
```

Meaning, if the `scope` is not given as argument, it defaults to the next value of a hidden global `counter` which is incremented every time `isolate()` is called.

In conclusion, `isolate(component, scope)` is referentially transparent because we give the `scope`, but `isolate(component)` is not.

Comment: ok I understand. Thanks for the clarification. I came to think that it was probably because the component function was not pure (in the example you give in the page, the component queries a DOM class. At one point that returns one element; when you add the second slider, that returns two = so same input (the class), different outputs). But then if I understand now, you chose to 'purify' the component function, by adding the random scope, and that at the cost of an impure `isolate` function.